# Eclipse RSE (Remote System Explorer) SSH issue

Tags: eclipse, ssh

Running Eclipse on Ubuntu 11.10 in Virtual Box (host OS is Windows 7), I get an error message (RSEG 1066: Failed to connect sshd with detail of "timeout: socket is not established") when I attempt to connect to my Beaglebone board over Ethernet. I am able to use PuTTY under Ubuntu to make this connection successfully. Does anyone know if there are Eclipse settings which may be preventing this?